# bash read csv file store value into a variable

Tags: bash

I would like to read csv using Bash and store each value into a variable for further processing. 
my csv file looks like below, all the values are unique.

```
> val1-row1,val2-row1,val3-row1,val4-row1....valn-row1
> val1-row2,val2-row2,val3-row2,val4-row2....valn-row2
```

My code below

```
 while IFS=, read eachvalue; 
    do
   if [ "$eachvalue" = "something" ]
   then
    echo "do something"
   else
    echo "do something else"
   fi
    done < allvalues.csv
```

I am unable to read each value and do if condition for each value in csv file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you could tell us your complete requirement it is quite possible that we could do this with a single awk or sed etc. So kindly edit your post with more details.

Comment: my csv file contains unique values with multiple columns, there are no quotes or dashes in the values. each value is separated by comma.All are unique values. I would like to read each value into a variable (only variable) and check against another set of values (they are from another file). If both match, I do certain echo commands. Thanks again !

Comment: What do you mean by "only variable"? And if you're checking against a set read from another file, doing that efficiently in native bash calls for using associative arrays, or changing out your toolset entirely (if you're focused on throughput, ditching bash entirely and writing your code in 100% awk -- not awk-embedded-in-bash -- is a good choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFS=,` is only useful if you're using `read -a` to read into an array, or you pass one variable name per column you want to read. Below, we do the former:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ -- NOT /bin/sh

row_idx=0
while IFS=, read -ra values; do
  for col_idx in "${!values[@]}"; do value=${values[$col_idx]}
    if [ "$value" = something ]; then
      echo "something found on row $row_idx, column $col_idx"
    fi
  done
  (( ++row_idx ))
done
```

See this running at https://ideone.com/JN1pK3, with the output (after inserting `something` into the second line of input, next to the end): `something found on row 1, column 4` (keeping in mind that both rows and columns are zero-indexed).